# How would “bury the light” be translated into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

This is a phrase for a new hat that I want to get embroidered possibly tomorrow and I have a few ideas of what it could be but I don’t trust myself that much yet haha. Please help, thanks!

Comment: I think we'll need more context to be able to translate that. For example, do you mean to say that light is dead and is to be buried like a corpse or that the light should be hidden thoroughly? And does light mean literal light or something spiritual? Please [edit] to add details of the context.

Comment: If you want to produce a physical item tomorrow, asking today is a bit late. You may well get an answer within a day, but don't count on that, or on the first answer being the best one. Waiting a bit longer is likely to reward you with a better translation.

Comment: Yes I mean that the light is dead. Thanks so much! I would be interested to know both versions though.

Answer (score 2):

“To bury” as in a grave is *sepeliō, sepelīre, sepelīvī, sepultum* (*sepultō, sepultāre, sepultāvī, sepultātum* is properly “to hold buried,” which is the “action” of the grave itself); “light” is either *lūx, lūcis* (feminine) or *lūmen, lūminis* (neuter). So I'd render it as ***Sepelīte lūmen*** or ***Sepelīte lūcem.***

Note that I'm using the plural imperative (You all, bury the light); the singular imperative, if you are speaking to a single person, would be just *sepelī* instead. If you think that *sepeliō* is ugly, you can use *obruō, obruere, obruī, obrutum* (the primary sense of which is “overwhelm” or “overthrow”) can be used, instead: *Obruite lūmen.*

Answer (score 1):

The "sepelire lumen" metaphor is inexistent in latin (there is no 1:1 analogy of metaphors between languages!). Cicero says several times "lumen exstinguere", "to extinguish the light".

Comment: You could potentially do "bury the lamp." It's not an attested idiom, but it wouldn't be impossible to figure out. I agree though that using *lumen* or *lux* here sounds odd.

Comment: It's not exactly an idiom in English either, so looking for strictly attested parallels is the wrong way to go about it.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestions would be "*Sepelias lucem!*" and "*Sinas lucem in sepulcrum.*" ("*Put the light in a grave.*").

Comment: Note that *sino* is quite unnatural choice. even if it can mean *to put* when in active, this is most certainly not the main use of that verb. It reads more like: let the light be in the cave - i.e., let it go, leave it, allow it. Also, the present subjective is little surprising  - but it might be defended if OP provides more context.